# How to create an Async/await Method for Watin?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, watin

I am trying to make my Main module to await for a method to be done.

Take a look at the following code:

```
Public static void CheckAvailItem(IE browser)
    {

       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {             
            browser.CheckBox(Find.ById("PickUpItem" + i)).Checked = true;                           
        }
    }
```

The method simply Checks 6 CheckBoxes. The problem with WatIn is that there is a delay of around 1 second in between each "check" of each Checkbox, and the issue is that the main program keeps running and does not wait for the six boxes to be checked.

I was trying to accomplish this by using asynchronous programming but I am having a hard time creating it.

I know that the Async keyword goes in between "static" and "void" but I don't know where to put the "await" keyword. I tried putting it behind "browser" but I know it should not be there.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why do you want to make this particular method async? What do you expect to gain with it? To learn the basics on `async-await` take a look at my [async-await general curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general).

Comment: Well, This methods takes, lets say, six seconds to complete. I dont know what WatIn takes so long to check the checkboxes. In the mean time, the rest of the code keeps executing, it does not wait for the Method to be completed. I know I can do something like Await Task.Delay(6000) but the time varies. I feel like theres a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Task.Run`?

Comment: can you detect somehow when checkbox is checked? (any events or something like that)?

Comment: Exactly ! I need to detect somehow when the checkbox is checked. I dont know if WatIn has such method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.I figure it out. I include a Thread.Sleep and it worked.